# Android EditText's cursor coordinates (absolute position)

Tags: android, coordinates, android-edittext, cursor-position

How can I get the coordinates of the cursor in the EditText ? I am not trying to get the cursor position here but the EditText coordinates of the cursor.

In my case, when I send a number via KeyEvent to the EditText, the cursor position (getSelectionStart) is changed, but its location is always at the right of the EditText.

I want to know the coordinates of the cursor (the right of the EditText).

Comment: Can you pls. show a quick example on how u `send a number via KeyEvent to the EditText`. Thx.

Comment: sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1);

Comment: It wroks, too
mInstrumentation.sendStringSync("1");

Comment: I mean, I want to write a UT program to automatically send the keyEvent to EditText, then check if the cursor is always at the right of the EditText. I can do the first thing, but have no idea to do the second thing

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit late answer :), but from API level 21 (Lollipop) there is a way to do it:

- Override [`onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo(CursorAnchorInfo cursorAnchorInfo)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo(android.view.inputmethod.CursorAnchorInfo) in your InputMethodService
- and call [`inputConnection.requestCursorUpdates(int cursorUpdateMode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#requestCursorUpdates(int)) with CURSOR_UPDATE_MONITOR flag after you got the inputConnection.

The `onUpdateCursorAnchorInfo` will be called every time the cursor's position has changed. You can access the cursor's top right coordinates by `cursorAnchorInfo.getInsertionMarkerHorizontal()` (x) and `cursorAnchorInfo.getInsertionMarkerTop()` (y).